# Allow a 30-second grace period to change a Leave Open review

Tags: feature-request, review, grace-period

Correct me if I'm wrong, but currently there are extremely few actions without a short grace period in which you can undo them (in some way). Why is the "Leave Open" button in the close vote review queue an exception? I only rarely mess up, usually while on my phone, but there seems to be a clear precedent of 'undo-ability' that's broken here. Can we add a very short grace period so I can hit the back button and correct my review?

Comment: Have fun with review audits on your phone then -- if you get review banned it's unlikely that they'll be sympathetic for accidentally pressing the wrong button.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Not reviewing on my phone on the way to class is definitely an option, but I'd prefer that this feature was implemented so I can contribute more frequently to the CV queue.